# OpenNi2 and Asus Xtion Pro Live device not found

Tags: ubuntu, openni, asus-xtion

I'm getting crazy... It just doesnt work:
I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64bit edition.
After updating the whole system I installed what I think are all of the packages needed for OpenNI2: `sudo apt-get install g++ python libusb-1.0-0-dev libudev-dev openjdk-6-jdk freeglut3-dev doxygen graphviz -y`.
After that I downloaded the OpenNI2 Version 2.2.0.32 Beta Linux x64.
After unpacking I ran the install.sh with no errors.
Then plugging in the sensor, lsusb output:
`Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1d27:0601 ASUS`
But when I try to run the SimpleViewer example, I always get the following error:
`After initialization:

SimpleViewer: Device open failed:

    DeviceOpen using default: no devices found`

Thanks for your help:

Answer (score 3):

Just for update this for Ubuntu 14 and the new repository should use the following commands.

```
# Build OpenNI
git clone https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2.git
cd OpenNI2 && make -j4
```

Only Xtion ID 1d27:0601 ASUS is working but not the 0600 for a descriptor problem. more info [here](http://libusb.6.n5.nabble.com/How-to-set-the-USB-transfer-type-manually-td5710582.html)

Answer (score 2):

Same issue with Structure Sensor and PrimeSense on 14.04 32bit and 64bit, showing as Device `ID 1d27:0600 ASUS`

Solution was to create a symbolic link from the `libudev.so.0` file it seems OpenNI2 is expecting to find.

Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.3.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

Ubuntu 15.04

```
$ sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

Then just run your `./NiViewer` and smile.

I followed directions here:
http://codeyarns.com/2015/09/28/no-devices-found-error-with-openni2/

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when using the OpenNI 2 binary drivers from their web site.

I got it to work with compiling from source.

You have to install both the **OpenNI driver** for the Xtion and **OpenNI 2 itself**.

Try this:

```
# Build OpenNI driver for PrimeSense devices (Asus Xtion in our case)
git clone git@github.com:PrimeSense/Sensor.git
cd Sensor
cd Platform/Linux/CreateRedist && ./RedistMaker && cd ../../..
cd Platform/Linux/Redist && cd Sensor-Bin-* && sudo ./install.sh && cd ../../../../../

# Build OpenNI
git clone -b develop git@github.com:OpenNI/OpenNI2.git
cd OpenNI2 && make -j4 && cd ..

# Plug in the camera and try the viewer
cd OpenNI2/Bin/x64-Release && ./NiViewer
```

I used the `develop` branch of OpenNI above because `master` had some small (fixable) build errors.

Please tell me if this worked for you as well!

Comment: These instructions are great! But when I try to run NiViewer, I'm getting the following error: `freeglut (./Sample-NiSimpleViewer): Unable to create OpenGL 1.0 context (flags 0, profile 0)`. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Parallels 9 on a MBP. Do you have any suggestions? It seems like it's unable to start OpenGL within parallels.

Comment: Yes, that looks like you don't have OpenGL support in you VM. I've never used Parallels, but as far as I know this should be supported, so maybe you don't have it enabled or need to install a driver on the guest.